# Externally disable link embedded in .swf file?

Tags: flash

I inherited a project from a lax developer who left me NO source files. On the main page of our website is a .swf file in which the previous developer embedded an incorrect link. So now the Flash movie links to a page that is no longer active, which is frustrating. I have only the .swf file, no .fla files. Is there any way to externally disable the link embedded in the .swf file?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you just make the bad link a redirect to where it should link?

Comment: This is actually what we ended up doing. :)

Comment: I ran into this with a WordPress plugin and ended up just creating an empty `<div>` with a higher z-index value to invisibly cover up the Flash movie. Wish there was a better way ...

Answer (score 3):

You can disable all links within the SWF directly using parameters in your html object:
param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never"
param name="allowNetworking" value="internal"

Answer (score 0):

The problem with setting "allowScriptAccess" to "never" is that it removes the ability to control the object with Javascript. Eugene M provided the correct answer, which is to place a transparent div on top of the Flash movie using a higher z-index. I wrote about this [here](http://glassocean.net/how-to-disable-outbound-links-in-embedded-swf/).